# JQuery DataTable style not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to add jquery data tables to a simple aspx page. Did this before a couple times but this website that I'm adding it to now has some CSS that is getting inherited.
So I took the generated HTML and removed the CSS that was getting added to it.
My page still does not style properly!

Here is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <link href="CSS/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="CSS/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#gvMain").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).
                    dataTable({
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                    });
            });
        </script>
        <div>
            <form>
                <table id="gvMain">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Some Id</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gridItem">
                        <td>297</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gridAlternatingItem">
                        <td>296</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gridItem">
                        <td>295</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gridAlternatingItem">
                        <td>295</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gridItem">
                        <td>294</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gridAlternatingItem">
                        <td>294</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gridItem">
                        <td>293</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="gridAlternatingItem">
                        <td>293</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It looks like below

[image: bad looking]

I have spent hours trying to get it to work but no luck. It is in the main directory of the existing site though. But that should not matter right coz the HTML does not have anything included in it.

This is the screenshot of four errors that are showing in the above screenshot. It is nothing but some missing images/css files. 
[image: error image]

Comment: In your second screenshot. i can see 4 errors. maybe there is something that can help us in there ? can you paste them here ?

Comment: Updated question with error screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tag

Here is example of table:

```
  <table id="gvMain">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th scope="col">Some Id</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="gridItem">
          <td>297</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridAlternatingItem">
          <td>296</td>
      </tr>
          <tr class="gridItem">
      <td>295</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridAlternatingItem">
        <td>295</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridItem">
        <td>294</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridAlternatingItem">
        <td>294</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridItem">
        <td>293</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridAlternatingItem">
        <td>293</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```